# Why am I getting a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when nothing is being removed?

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I am getting a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when I run the following code:

```
public HashMap<String, String> instanceByPort() {
    HashMap<String, String> instances = new HashMap<String,String>();

    SimpleSNMPClient client = new SimpleSNMPClient("udp:" + hostname + "/161", communityString);
    try {
        instances = client.getTableAsStringsFlippedNoOID(new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1"));

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = instances.entrySet().iterator() ;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String, String> instance = iterator.next();
            String key = instance.getKey();
            String value = instance.getValue();
            instances.put(value, key);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("instanceByPort failed. " + e);
    }
    return instances;
}
```

and a bit of searching suggests this happens when you're removing elements from a HashMap as you're iterating through it.  But, as you can see, I'm not removing anything.

What gives?

Comment: You're changing the collection, `instances.put(value, key);`, while iterating through it. This looks like a setup for this exception, no?

Comment: _"a bit of searching suggests this happens when you're removing elements from a HashMap"_ If you look at the documentation of `HashMap` you would see that it states: _"The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: if the map **is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created**, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iterator` is backed by `instances`, and the loop modifies `instances` (by calling `instances.put`).

Therefore, you are modifying `instances` while (concurrent to) iterating over its entries.

Comment: Of course.  This is embarrassing.  I wanted to copy one of those hashes to a new hash.

Answer (score 1):

As its name implies, this exception is thrown when the source collection is modified in any way.

Adding to the map is also a modification.